# Disable remote controls iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

By default, remote control is activated on my streaming application but under a certain circumstance I want to disable all controllers and show nothing when the screen is locked.

First I tried to set now playing info to nil like this `[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo: nil];` and all text, image and progress disappear but the control buttons and volume bar was still showing.

After that I tried this `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] endReceivingRemoteControlEvents];` but it gives me nothing, it shows the same thing on the screen as the previous method call.

For the record, I'm calling `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];` on AppDelegate before I tried to call any of the previous methods.

So, I have not found anything related to this that could help me with my problem and I would appreciate any help :)

Comment: "remote control is activated on my streaming application" How?

Comment: I activated "Audio, AirPlay and Picture in Picture" in Background Modes of my project capabilities